# AWS Cognito email confirmation not redirect to my website

Tags: redirect, amazon-cognito, confirmation

I am using aws cognito as federation service, it works fine except the email confirmation, it redirects me to aws confirmation page (little box) after clicking the confirmation link.

I want it to redirect me to my page, It gives me a link like:

`https://<MY-DOMAIN>.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/confirmUser?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&user_name=<USERNAME>&confirmation_code=<CODE>`

But I need something like:

`https://<MY-DOMAIN>.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/confirmUser?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&user_name=<USERNAME>&confirmation_code=<CODE>&redirect_uri=https://www.MYWEBSITE.com/WELCOME`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please configure Call Back URLs in your App Client Settings inside App Integration which is part of AWS Cognito user Pool.

Comment: These callbacks for Sign-in / Sign-out, not for confirmation email

Comment: Confirmation emails can be customized from 'Message customizations' link in AWS Cognito user pool.

Comment: The message is `Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##} `, how could you customize it?

Comment: If each message needs to be customized, with your custom fields, you need to use Lambda Triggers in AWS Cognito user pool. There is a trigger placeholder for Custom message. This trigger is invoked before a verification or MFA message is sent, allowing you to customize the message dynamically. Note that static custom messages can be edited on the Verifications panel. Full documentation is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html